# Installing the new version on JUnit in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I'm trying to update the JUInt version to be the latest `5.4.2` in order to use the `assertDoesNotThrow` function. I downloaded `junit-jupiter-api` from [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.junit.jupiter%20AND%20v:5.4.2) and set it in `Project structure -> Modules -> Dependecies -> +`.

But when I ran the following part of code:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
```

I get the following error:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.ComparisonFailure
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:207)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:61)
```

But the version is set to be `5.4.2` I don't understand where is the problem. How to solve it?

**EDIT**: The command I ran:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6\lib\idea_rt.jar=65501:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\HW\out\production\HW;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6\plugins\junit\lib\opentest4j-1.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6\plugins\junit\lib\junit-jupiter-api-5.4.2.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 Testing.Test.Example
```

Comment: To make it easier to manage the versions of specific libraries maybe consider using some mangement tools like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)?

Comment: You either have some old junit jar in the classpath or you didn't include all the dependencies. See also http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea..

Comment: @PiotrS I'm trying to run a test I was given to by my professor. but I fail to set the JUInt.

Comment: You probably need to use a JUnit version before 5. It changed a lot.

Comment: The test uses `assertDoesNotThrow` and as I understand it was enabled only in Junit5. Anyway, my profs said to use the `5.4.2` version just can't seem to understand why. Please checkout the command I ran - maybe youll find something I missing. Maybe the reason is `junit-rt.jar`?